# What method or way can I use to turn a string entered by the user to an integer in C++

Tags: c++

Let say the user input a value like so:
1000 1345 890 896 as string how do I convert them to integer in C or C++. The reason being that I'm am creating some kind of number decoding system and I need all the numbers to be entered inline regardless of the length the space will denote the end of each number entered.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Read up on [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).  That's the right answer for both languages.

Comment: Pick C or C++. They are different languages and the "natural" solutions can be very different.

Comment: Yes tried to convert to char then to corresponding int but the problem is when the number exceed 100's

Comment: Show your code and explain what the specific problem is.

Comment: @JohnIsaac, `char` is an unsigned integer type that stores a value between 0 and 256.

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) , [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) & [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for the three most obvious options.

Comment: @SumnerEvans `char` may be signed or unsigned with a range of `[-128, 127]` or `[0, 255]` respectively.

Comment: @NathanOliver, good clarification. It is clear that the OP does not even understand that a `char` is actually just an integer. *"Yes tried to convert to char then to corresponding int but the problem is when the number exceed 100's"*

Comment: @NathanOliver -- `char` may be signed or unsigned with a **minimum** range of [-127, 127] and [0, 255] respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Got a way out thanks to everyone

Would have put the code up but can't actually get indenting on stack right. Because I'm actually new to stack so I'm  going to skip putting up the code anyway I used the string to integer function I noticed it was my compiler that was giving me the problem @first because it doesn't support C++11 library functions, it's an outdated compiler I'm guessing C++99.

Anyway thanks to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple code to get you started.  Of course there is no checking here to see if the user is inputting correct format, so you can get a runtime error.  I also haven't provided a way out of the loop because I don't know what you need the string to look like to know that you're done collecting strings.  It also just throws the integers in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    std::string str;
    while (std::cin >> str)
        {
        int num = std::stoi(str);
        nums.push_back(num);
        }
    return 0;
}
```